# Options for game development with MonoTouch

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios

What options are there for game developers in regards to working with the [MonoTouch](http://monotouch.net) framework?

1. Is OpenGL fully supported? Or just a subset?
2. Is there any additional tools, frameworks or engines that would be compatible with MonoTouch? Would these libraries also have to be written in .NET?
3. Do you have any other tips?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

OpenGL is fully supported in MonoTouch, we distribute OpenTK with support for OpenGL ES 1 and ES 2, so it has a nice binding that you can use from managed languages like C#.

[As the previous poster hinted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1513085/7724), there is XnaTouch available today, and there is some talk about bringing Cocos2D on the Monotouch-o-sphere.

An alternative to using MonoTouch with OpenGL or XnaTouch is to use another Mono-based framework that is entirely focused on gaming, the Unity3D platform.   This is a professional tool for building 3D and 2D games and goes beyond what Xna does, it is an entire gaming IDE with a full game engine.

Comment: Thanks Miguel for enlightening me!

Comment: Unfortunately, there seem to be no profiling options if you go with MonoTouch/OpenTK. Apple's XCode has powerful profiling options which allow you to see the bottlenecks of your OpenGL rendering pipeline, but you cannot use them if you're on MonoTouch. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12223401/is-there-something-like-xcodes-opengl-frame-capture-for-monotouch

Answer (score 1):

- [XNATouch](http://xnatouch.codeplex.com/): Free implementation of the XNA Framework for MonoTouch
- [unity3d](http://unity3d.com/unity/features/scripting): C# game library for iPhone. It's based on Mono but don't think it is related to MonoTouch.