# Any chance of cocos2d within MonoTouch?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, xamarin.ios, cocos2d-iphone

After learning more about how monotouch works, I believe I know the answer to this anyway, but can you use the cocos2d-iphone framework with monotouch? I believe most likely this will be a 'no', because cocos2d is an an objective c library and there would most probably have to be some sort of .net port for this to be achieved? is that so?

I haven't done any monotouch dev as yet, but a little objective c development with cocos2d and am quite fond of the framework, and was hoping to avoid, as I'm quite new to game dev, steeping into the dark realm of straight opengl programming via the openTK interface supported by monotouch.

I have also started a community wiki [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512760/options-for-game-development-with-monotouch) for people to share game development options on monotouch which should help us all with this emerging framework.

Comment: Wow, I just assumed that Monotouch had full access to cocos2d and all other libs. Huge eye opener. I'll stick with Obj-C ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cocos2D is being ported to MonoTouch:
http://github.com/city41/cocosnet

Comment: I have not seen any code updates for 2-3 years on this project.

Comment: My answer here is also that old :) Yeah, unfortunately for various reasons CocosNet never succeeded. I have no real plans of working on it again, as I've moved onto other engines to create my games. The game I wrote with CocosNet will most likely get ported to Unity. Other people did fork CocosNet on github, but if I had to guess those forks are dead too.

Answer (score 6):

Update:

There are two options, you can use the Cocos2D binding on MonoTouch, using the bindings as published here:

https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings/tree/master/cocos2d

Or you can use Cocos2D ported to XNA:

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/archives/1801

Comment: Are there any performance hits taken by using cocos2d bindings with monotouch? I'm thinking about moving some code for a game to monotouch but don't want to commit to buying a license unless I know its a viable option.

Answer (score 1):

It seems CocosNet has gone untouched for some time now[a]... Is it still being developed or should you go with Objective C if you want to use Cocos2D?

[a] http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=1251007

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any experience with MonoTouch, but you might want to see if you can get [Farseer Physics](http://www.codeplex.com/FarseerPhysics) working with MonoTouch. Farseer is based on Box2D, which is also a component of Cocos2d.

Answer (score 0):

Good news is that the c++ version, cocos2d-x, has been [ported to run on XNA](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/archives/1801) for Windows Phone7. This should make it also able to run on Monotouch. I was very impressed with MonoTouch but for cocos2D I'd be inclined to go with straight cocos2d-x unless you desperately want to program in C#.

Answer (score 0):

you can find an XNA version of cocos2d at https://github.com/Cocos2DXNA/cocos2d-xna. This works on MonoTouch, MonoDroid, Windows, Mac, Ouya, Xbox. It even has a high performance box2d implementation that runs as fast as the C++ box2d (at 60 fps, except for the AddPair test).

```
cocos2dxna.codeplex.com for our forums
www.cocos2dxna.com for the web site that we recently started
nuget.cocos2dxna.com/nuget for the nuget repository
www.facebook.com/Cocos2DXNA for our facebook page
```