# Is there something like XCode's OpenGL Frame Capture for MonoTouch?

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin.ios, opengl-es-2.0, xamarin

XCode's 'Frame Capture' feature is here since XCode 4.2.

Is there a similar feature in MonoTouch, or is it possible to leverage XCode's feature in a MonoTouch project?

@Xamarin people: If not, are there any plans to support something like this?

Comment: Please, Xamarin. At least a comment on this.